# Blazor WASM passing obj to JS empty unless serialised as json. Other objects work

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, interop, webassembly

Essentially I can only pass primitives and anonymous types as argument in Blazor interop with JS.

My first post on stack overflow ever because I just cant figure this out:

This example works:

C#:

```cs
 async void doThing()
{
  await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("test", new { Name = "John", Age = 35 });
}
```

JS:

```js
 var test = funciton(stuff){
  console.log(stuff);
  return stuff;
}

Output in JS is object with name and age as expected.
```

Now here's my actual class:

```cs
 public class CarsAndBikes
    {
        public car[] cars;
        public bike[] bikes;
    }

 async void doThing()
{
  await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("test", carsAdnBikes);
}
```

Its not that complex but what I can see in JS is an empty object, unless I serialise it as JSON and deserialise. car and bike are classes.
C#

```cs
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CarsAndBikes);
```

JS:

```js
JSON.parse(stuff)
```

Then it works fine. I have no idea why I cannot pass my class to JS, does anyone know if Im doing something wrong or its a bug?

Comment: You might want to include the code that is not working - you have shown code that does work so far...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working demo using your code.  It works, so there's something your not showing us that breaks your code.  What does `Car` and `Bike` look like?

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime Js

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=doThing>Object</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick=doBookThing>Book as Object</button>
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=doBook>Book</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" @onclick=doBooks>Books</button>
@code
{
    async void doThing()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("test", new { ID = 1, Title = "Fred" });
    }

    async void doBookThing()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("test", new Book { ID = 1, Title = "Portugal" });
    }
    async void doBook()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<Book>("test", new Book { ID = 1, Title = "Shaun" });
    }

    async void doBooks()
    {
        await Js.InvokeAsync<object>("test", new Catalog());
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class Catalog
    {
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book> {
            new Book { ID=10, Title="Jon" },
            new Book { ID=11, Title="Spain" }
        };
    }
}
```

[image]